# Nested If in DataStage Transformer

Tags: if-statement, nested, datastage, transformer-model

I am using below nested if condition in transformer. How ever it is giving error. Can some one assist me to resolve the error:

IF  IsNotNull(lnkReadHabsClob.NUM_57_A)
THEN 
     ( IF  LEN57A < 2 THEN Trim(lnkReadHabsClob.BENEFICIARY_FI_SKEY_57A)
       ELSE IF LEN57A > 2 THEN Trim(lnkReadHabsClob.BENEFICIARY_FI_SKEY_57A[LEN57A,11] ) )
ELSE 
( IF IsNotNull(lnkReadHabsClob.NUM_58_A) AND LEN58A < 2 THEN TRIM(lnkReadHabsClob.BENEFICIARY_FI_SKEY_58A) 
  ELSE IF IsNotNull(lnkReadHabsClob.NUM_58_A) AND LEN58A > 2 THEN TRIM(lnkReadHabsClob.BENEFICIARY_FI_SKEY_58A[LEN58A,11]) )
  ELSE lnkReadHabsClob.BENEFICIARY_FI_SKEY_58A)

Answer (score 0):

First of all formatting is a problem - with a text formatted like that in your question no one can see anything.

After formatting it I suggest you

- Check the substring [LEN58A,11] - what do you mean with LEN58A ? 
  If this is not a stage variable it might be your problem (used more than once)
- Same potential problem with the condition:  LEN57A < 2
- There is a  LEN57A < 2 and LEN57A > 2 condition but what if it is equals 2 - but this is only a potential logic problem